# Java JDBC driver for xls/x

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, apache-poi, resultset

One of my project needs an JDBC driver to read xls/x file as a resultset.
I came across SQLSheet but there are some issues with it. And then there is XLS JDBC, which do not support xlsx files.

I can read the files using Apache POI, but I am not allowed to change the existing implementation. If you are aware of any such api please let me know.

Thanks
Hanumant

Comment: I'm quite sure that [MS Access DB Redist](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) over JDBC/ODBC will handle both xls and xlsx. Is *nix a requirement?

Comment: The database if Oracle and is hosted on Unix server. Any other solution.

Comment: So you want to import xls/x into Oracle? and there's some importing tool,  which is based on result sets and it needs to run on the same server as the Oracle DB? is it a java stored procedure? if you don't find a convenient jdbc driver, I would simply write a tool, which imports the sheet(s) into scratch tables and give the importing tool a result set on them, along with a database jobs which drops the tables after N minutes of creation